# Solution of least-squares problems \vert(x*s-e)\vert with Ax=b

Tags: optimization, least-squares

Considering the following problem

$\min ∥xs-e∥$  s.t   $Ax=b$

,where we know that $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $b$ is vector $m\times1$ .

Also vector $s$ is a $n\times1$ matrix with all its elements not negative

and $e$ is the vector with all its components equal to $1$.

$xs$ is the Hadamard product of $x$ and $s$ .

Comment: [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

This is an easy to formulate and solve convex linearly-constrained least squares (2-normn) problem using CVX, CVXPY or similar tool.

In CVX under MATLAB:

```
cvx_begin
variable x(n)
minimize(norm(x.*s - 1))
subject to
A*x == b
cvx_end
```

Comment: Can you explain to me without MATLAB?
A handy solution to that.

Comment: You need to solve a linearly constrained least squares problem. There are packages to do that in many computing environments, including R and Python. This can (also) be solved as a Quadratic Programming problem, or reformulated to be a Second Order Cone Problem (SOCP).